# Only querying specific nodes in a Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am setting up Neo4j database to collect multiple isolated graphs (on which queries may or may not be run together.)

For instance:
The graph in the attached image is a disjoint union of three complete graphs, and I want to have three endpoints for the three different graphs and one for the complete graph (i.e. all three complete graphs.)

`runQueryOnSubgraph1?query="Match (n)-->(m) return n;" //output will include the nodes 16 to 35`
`runQueryOnSubGraph2?query="Match (n) return n;" //output will include the nodes 11 to 15`
`runQueryOnFullGraph?query="Match (n) return n;" //output will include the nodes 1 to 35`

Every node in each disjoint subgraph does has a unique property (like n.subgraph = {1,2,3}), so one doesn't necessarily need to run a connected components finder every time.

[image: A graph which is a disjoint union of 3 complete graphs]

I don't want to pass the burden of having where clauses to the users, which is why I am looking for an automated conditioning logic. And since the query can have any number of variables (eg. n, m in the first query), I can not think of a general `where` clause on the variable names. Also, the subgraph may not be connected so solution like `apoc.path.subgraphAll` will not work.

Ideally, what I want is something like:
`"Match (n)-->(m) return n" + " where (p:*) p.subgraph = 1"` where every node being referred in the query should have a property `subgraph` and it must be equal to `1`.

Any pointers/ideas would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I have a very inefficient solution based on the fact that since the subgraphs are all complete, each subgraph has a path from n to n.

You could try logic that goes like this:

1. Find paths of arbitrary length from (n) to (n)
2. Find the longest of each path. This will traverse each node in the subgraph that n is in.
3. Collect all the longest paths in a list so you have nodes n1, n2, etc. and their longest paths
4. Take the first item in the list (since each path contains all nodes). Now you have nodes n1, n2, etc. and 1 path that traverses each node in its subgraph.
5. Aggregate by length of path (assuming all subgraphs are different sizes)
6. Take the first path for each length
7. Label each node in each path with a label or property

If you can identify one specific node in each graph, you can modify this logic to avoid producing O(n!) paths.

I can come up with some rough code for this, just let me know.

Comment: Oh, I use disjoint graphs in the example above, but as I explain later; that may not be the case. Hence anything related to paths will not work.

Comment: Okay interesting. If they're not disjoint, how are you identifying subgraphs?

Comment: *Oops, I meant connected; the subgraphs may not be connected and every node in each subgraph does has a unique property (like n.subgraph = {1,2,3})

Comment: How about finding weakly-connected components? This algorithm will return an ID for each component in the graph. https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/wcc/

Comment: The issue will be that it will be quite slow, I just need a global filter on the node property named "subgraph"...

Comment: I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to create a property "subgraph" that you could filter on later, but that property already exists?

Please clarify a little more for me: you said each node has n.subgraph = {1, 2, 3} which means n is a part of subgraphs 1, 2, and 3? You also say that "every node being referred to in the query should have a property subgraph and it must be equal to 1." I don't quite know how to put these two things together.